# what are the compression forces in a strut if the strut is fixed

Tags: structural-engineering, structural-analysis, statics

i am trying to match an experiment i have done and i dont know how to compute the force in the strut in terms of F given these boundary conditions. i have attempted to use fixed end moment equations but cant find anything suitable, can anyone help as to why this might not work or how it might work?

[image]

Comment: Looks to me like taking moments about the point where the wing joins the wall should work.  Where did you get stuck?

Comment: @DanielHatton the two reaction forces at the pin plus the moment and reaction force from the strut create for unknowns with only three equations (force up and sideways and moment balance) that is too many unknowns and not enough equations.

Comment: The moment and reaction force from the strut are not really two different unknowns: one is defined in terms of the other.  Oh, or do you mean there's a terminal couple on the strut?

Comment: In the latter case, you can probably get a fourth equation by taking moments about the point where the strut joins the wall.

Comment: If everything is fixed, and providing moments, you will have to find the resulting state - this would be where deflections agree (taking into account elastic modulus and the like).  The simplification in truss design involves approximating all links as only providing loads along their axis, but you will get closer to reality by modeling what you really have.

Comment: One further thought about the possibility of there being a terminal couple on the strut: the purpose of having this sort of diagonal-strut arrangement (as opposed to clamping the left-hand end of the wing and letting it bear the full bending moment due to $F$ in flexure) is to avoid (at least partly) getting material into tension (because a lot of materials are weaker in tension than in compression).  If you allow there to be a terminal couple on the strut, you risk putting one face of the strut into tension.